# Lirc Configuration Dialog Not Coming Up After Install

Tags: lirc

When I follow every guide I can find about LIRC they all talk about this configuration dialog that is supposed to pop up so I can set my remote IR receiver type, however when I do it I get no such dialog and therefore I cannot get my remote to work.  Why would the configuration dialog not pop up.

I have also tried the dpackage or whatever command and a bunch of text streams in the command line window but no pop up.

Please help.

Comment: Could you include output of the "bunch of text streams in the command line window" within your question?

Comment: Sure.  I can probably get to this Wednesday.  Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the functionality of lirc has been moved into the kernel on recent Ubuntu releases.

So, you need to uninstall lirc and make sure that `ir-keytable` is installed instead. Then, in `terminal` type `man ir-keytable` to get started.

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge lirc
sudo apt-get install ir-keytable
```

Plug in your remote dongle, and in `terminal`, type `ir-keytable` and this will give you the basic information you'll need to get started. Then use `ir-keytable -t` to get/review your scan codes. You'll save a keymap in `/etc/rc_keymaps` (*you can get a prebuilt keymap file from `/lib/udev/rc_keymaps/`*), and edit `/etc/rc_maps.cfg` if you need to.

**Update:**

In `terminal`...

```
sudo cp /lib/udev/rc_keymaps/rc6_mce /etc/rc_keymaps
```

If you Google `ir-keytable` you'll get plenty of how-to articles to help you. One good article is at http://madaboutbrighton.net/articles/2015/remote-control-media-player-without-lirc-using-ir-keymap

Comment: Thanks.  When I had installed LIRC in Mint, it popped up a super easy GUI that allowed me to select my dongle (which is a generic MCE dongle and a Logitech remote).  LIRC's website refers to this pop up so I figured something was going wrong but what you say makes sense from an ease of integration standpoint, I just think something is lost with the removal of the GUI setup.  In Mint this setup took 5 min, in Ubuntu it has taken several minutes over weeks.  Seems like a step backward for the end user even if it is an increase in efficiency for the developer.

Comment: Sorry but this is not helpful.  Your answer is not straight forward to a non linux user.  

Can someone just please give me the file I need and tell me where to download it to?

It is an RC6 profile.  I found it in /lib/udev/rc_keymaps/ the tried to copy it to /etc/rc_keymaps but it doesn't copy. 

$99 for windows 10 is starting to seem worth it.  It's too bad too.  I think there great potential in this platform if devs would just start caring about there end users instead of how cool they are.

Comment: @joewilkinson I sorry that you're frustrated. Did you look at the man page? Did you look at the link that I left for you? Did you Google `ir_keytable`? I gave you the basics to get you started. I can't give you an entire introductory lesson in this, or in Linux. That's left to the user to learn some of this on their own over time. To copy the default RC6 profile, do `sudo cp /lib/udev/rc_keymaps/rc6_mce /etc/rc_keymaps` in `terminal`.

Comment: @joewilkinson ps: after copying the RC6 keymap, reboot the computer, and if your remote is a standard MCE device, it'll probably work then.