# LIRC's "devinput" driver dead after upgrade to 17.04

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 17.04, lirc

I have been using the same IR reciever and remote for my HTPC build since 15.10 - I achieved this using **LIRC** with a custom lircd.conf. 
Recently, after I upgraded to 17.04, LIRC became unresponsive. After reading the logs and googling the issues I stumbled [upon this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=662071)
This guy's/gal's thread documents his issues with LIRC's devinput driver after updating from Fedora 12 to 14, to be specific, the **remote stopped working completely**. While searching for the solution, the poster tried **changing** LIRC's **driver to "default"**, which made the remote work, but only sometimes.

The same thing happened to me, I am currently running LIRC with the "default" driver, and here's how I would describe the issues: the remote starts "working" but not all button presses work all the time; to be exact, it seems in my case that LIRC almost "falls asleep", so it will ignore all the button presses unless you make them around 4-5 times in succession really fast (making 1 click per 2 seconds doesn't "wake it up"). After that, all the button presses get recognized without issues.

I tried launching "irw" to check that **it's not just the applications ignoring LIRC**, and actually **LIRC being at fault here**, and it confirmed it: when the machine it in it's "glitched" state (asleep) irw doesn't report any button presses until you "wake LIRC up" with a quick succession of button presses.

Unfortunately, as far as I understand, **the issue reported on that forum was eventually fixed on kernel level** - and I think that leaves me basically helpless.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/914625/lirc-configuration-dialog-not-coming-up-after-install/914776#914776

Comment: Thank you. There's some progress, I managed to create a keymap for my remote (xbone media remote) and make it recognized on boot (it uses the NEC protocol, so had to specify that in the keymap). However, the applications themselves, be it Kodi or irexec, do not recognize half the buttons. The buttons are, however, recognized using "ir-keytable -t", so the keymap must be correct.

Comment: You might look in `/lib/udev/rc_keymaps/` for a prebuilt NEC map for your remote. I do believe that the button names may make a difference. See the bottom text at the link I previously provided.

Comment: I found "nec_terratec_cinergy_xs" in there and used the names provided in there for my own keymap (they seem identical to the ones I used for LIRC, but I decided to still use the ones provided, just in case) - still half the keys are not recognized, and it's not weird ones, it's the standard ones like "KEY_OK". Lircmap.xml in Kodi was changed to suit the new button names. Tried to look for keymaps made "specifically" for my remote, didn't find it there (not a surprise, really)

Comment: I've got two remotes myself. The ATI works 100%, but the generic MCE remote does the same as yours. I've only briefly played with fixing it, but haven't got the hang of it yet, so I can't give any more specific advice for you. Let me know if you figure it out so I can fix mine :-)

Comment: Replacing some keys works, like "KEY_OK" to "KEY_ENTER", but that's essentially emulating a keyboard - right? That's not how LIRC worked. Let me get this straight: LIRC support in Ubuntu is basically dead in later versions, because it moved to kernel, and Kodi doesn't properly support kernel input events. So people with IR remotes are basically screwed?

Comment: I suspect that's it still a work in progress. You might Google "lirc ir_keytable" and see what you get. I'd be interested to hear what you find in your research. I don't know when the changeover occurred. I'm still learning the ir_keytable ropes, when I have the time :-)

Comment: You might look at http://www.lirc.org/html/configuration-guide.html. I haven't digested it all, but it looks pretty in depth.

Comment: Please remember to vote on my other answer if it was helpful. Thanks!